# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

An exception occurred when I visit my jsp page reply.jsp and i cannot figure out why, any solutions or suggestions to fix this problem?

The exception is here.

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file:
>   [C:\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\ForumTest\org\apache\jsp\reply_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported.
>   javax.security.auth.message.callback.PrivateKeyCallback.Request
>   resolves to a package
>
> Stacktrace:
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

---

here is the 14th line in reply_jsp.java

```
import javax.security.auth.message.callback.PrivateKeyCallback.Request;
```

Comment: `javax.security.auth.message.callback.PrivateKeyCallback.Request` not presented in either classpath or lib folder.

Comment: Posting whole stack trace here is not help full to give an answer. Post some relevant code to understand others.